# guidance for working with STM32L476RG to complete my project

Tags: arm, keil

I bought a STM32L476RG Nucleo board which has a STM32 Cortex-M4 MCU. I'm trying to program it with Keil but I didn't find any example for my board. How to set up the keil for my board and start working  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unspecific question. Have a look at the [ST website for this board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-l476rg.html).
There is a lot of documentation, how to use this board with example code packages.

Another option is to install the [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/development-tools/software-development-tools/stm32-software-development-tools/stm32-configurators-and-code-generators/stm32cubemx.html) software. This tool can generate example code/projects for some IDEs incl. Keil µVision.